# How do I save label leaf (X1>0.5) in data.frame using R?

Tags: r, decision-tree

I am working on testing the result of different decision-trees, using R. I create 1000 tree with the same GDP, but from different samples to compare the results. So, I put the results in a data.frame. However, before I do this, I create a list with all my result.

**The problem is:** Instead the list saves the leaf as it is (for instance x1> 0.5) the list saves only leaf* . How could I save this label “x1>0.5” to compare the samples?

**Following an example in R:**

*Print the tree:*

```
print(tree_honest_CT1_prune_i)
```

*Result in R:*

```
[1] "CTD"
node), split, n, deviance, yval
      * denotes terminal node

1) root 333 644.3187 -4.874456  

  2) x1_i>=0.5 160 167.2816 -5.141895 *

  3) x1_i< 0.5 173 140.5346 -4.979827 *
```

*Create a list:* *N_loop: number the samples that I would like to have, in this case =1*

```
result_eq1_prune <- list (N_loop)

result_eq1_prune [i] <- tree_honest_CT1_prune_i

result_eq1_prune
```

*Result in R:*

```
[[1]]
     var   n  wt      dev      yval   complexity ncompete nsurrogate

1   x1_i 333 333 644.3187 -4.874456 0.0006157295        0          1

2 leaf* 160 160 167.2816 -5.141895 0.0000000000        0          0

3 leaf* 173 173 140.5346 -4.979827 0.0000000000        0          0
```

*between < >, I delete it in the example because it is not possibel writting in the forum.

Thank you!